# Obtener headers módulo angular

Tags: angular

soy nuevo en Angular y estoy intentando obtener todo los headers que devuelve una página web para analizar el tipo de seguridad que utilizan las mismas. Para ello estoy utilizando el módulo HttpHeaders pero no sé si es el correcto para el propósito que dispongo. A continuación pongo los pasos que he seguido

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpHeadersService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get("http://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

Tengo ese servicio, Todo lo necesario importado en el módulo de angular y después llamo al servicio desde un componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpHeadersService} from '../../services/http-headers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-form',
  templateUrl: './table-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-form.component.scss']
})
export class TableFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _httpHeadersService:HttpHeadersService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this._httpHeadersService.getData());
  }

}
```

Cuando hago esto se me imprime un Observable en consola, pero no sé si estoy haciendo el proceso bien o debería usar otro módulo ya que entrando en los campos del observable no veo ninguno esclarecedor que exponga todos los headers de la página en cuestión. ¿Alguna sugerencia o ayuda para hacer esto?. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Usando Angular 6/7, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

En tu service, asegurarte de que devuelves toda el objeto respuesta, no sólo los datos (del body):

```
getData(url) : Observable<HttpResponse<Object>>{
    return this.http.get<HttpResponse<Object>>(this.url, {observe: 'response'});
}
```

Y lo que te falta en tu componente es suscribirte al observable resultante:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._httpHeadersService.getData().subcribe(response => {
        const headers = response.getHeaders();
        const names= headers.getAll();
        names.forEach(headerName => console.log(headerName, headers.get(headerName)));
    });
}
```